# Can the Herald put itself on top of your draw deck?

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages

**Herald** from Dominion Guilds says that you can over pay for it and if you do, you may put X Action cards from your discard on top of your deck, where X is the amount you overpaid.

**Can you place Herald on top of your deck if you overpay?**

(Note: This question comes down to a matter of timing. Does the "when you buy this" clause occur before or after you place Hearld in the discard pile)

Answer (score 9):

**No, Herald cannot put itself on top of the deck by overpaying.**

From the [designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamedesigner/10525/donald-x-vaccarino), [Donald X. Vaccarino](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/12519698#12519698) on BGG.

> *Q: OK, so when the "when buy" effect kicks in, is the herald you just bought in the discard pile yet? Or would it have to be a "when gain" like Inn to do that? i.e., can you pay 5 to buy a herald and put it on top?*
>
> **A: When-buy, which includes overpay, triggers before gaining, so you can't buy a Herald and use its overpay to put that very Herald on top of your deck.**